# How can I get a form reference from a class by name using reflection in C#?

Tags: c#, forms, reflection, reference

I have a public static class called Router with some form references like this;

```
public static class Router
{
     static frmLogin rLogin = new frmLogin();
     static frmDashboard rDashboard = new frmDashboard();
     static frmReport rReport new frmReport();
}
```

I am trying to create a function called "Route" - this function will take a string parameter, which will match at least one of those form references. When matched, the selected form will have its "Index()" method invoked. (Every form has an Index() pre-built, I just need it called)

There's not too much to say about the purpose of this other than the fact that I'm creating an MVC-like structure for a very specific reason. So any other suggestions may be appreciated.

---

*To summarise, I need to find the correct Form reference by name i.e. "rLogin" using a parameter passed into the "Route" method, which will eventually call the "Index()" function on that form.*

I understand this may be possible with Reflection and I got a bit confused with other examples.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds a good use for dependency-injection. Instead of giving the router a string-reference of the class to be used, why not simply give it an instance of the class itself within the constructor?

```
interface IForm { }
class frmLogin : Form, IForm { }
class frmDashboard: Form, IForm { }
class frmReport: Form, IForm { }

public class Router
{
    IForm form;
    public Router(IForm form)
    {
        this.form = form; 
        this.form.Index();
    }      
}
```

How to create the router now? For example by using a `FormFactory` and then call `new Router(myFactory.CreateForm("frmLogin"))`.

```
class FormFactory {
    public IForm CreateForm(string name) {
        switch(name) {
            case: "frmLogin": return new frmLogin();
            case: "frmDashboard": return new frmDashboard();
            case: "frmReport": return new frmReport();
        }
    }    
}
```

EDIT: You may also extend your factory to create the instances only by their name:

```
public IForm CreateForm(string name) {
    return (IForm) Activator.CreateInstance(assembly, name);
}
```

But be aware that this will follows the workflow for dynamical assembly-loading including a fully-qualified typename and the assembly-name also. [See here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/d133hta4.aspx) how `CreateInstance` is used.

EDIT2: as of your edit you want to have only one instance per class to be returned by the router, so you may design the forms as singletons:

```
class frmLogin : Form, IForm {
    public static readonly Instance = new frmLogin();

    private frmLogin() { }
}
```

Now the factory-method slightly changes to something like this:

```
var type = myAssembly.GetType(name);
return (IForm) type.GetField("Instance", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static).GetValue(null);
```

Comment: So I'd implement it: 
Router obj = new Router(frmWhatever);
and it would instantiate and call the index function...

But doesn't this way create an object every time I'm routing to a different form? I only need the form's "Index()" method called once. I won't ever use any other properties or methods in that object

Also, I'm trying to re-use that single "Route" function for multiple possible class names, and all I have to work with is the string on the button that is clicked, that determined what the user wants to route to, and that's how I was hoping the appropriate class could be located.

Comment: So you want to ensure that every classes `Index`-method is called exactly once? Then you might add this functionality within the factory instead of the Routers constructor. Simply make the `Index`-method static and call it within the different cases: `frmLogin.Index()`. Within the method check if it was already called using a static variable within the class itself.

Comment: @BarryD. If you want a mapping from a string to a form, just use `Dictionary<string, IForm>`. But I'd do that as soon as possible, to keep the "non-safe" path as small as possible :)

Comment: @HimBromBeere that's beautiful, but will I need to add an additional case for every possible routing? This is why I was hoping for a more re-usable Function(FormName) sort of strategy, if that would work.

Comment: Yeap, however the same afford is needed in your current solution, as you have to modify the `Router` when adding a new form. There must be one place where you resolve the mapping from a string to an `IForm`, however the earlier you resolve this the better as Luaan already mentions.

Comment: Also see my last edit. It allows you to create the instances by name.

Comment: @HimBromBeere just for my understanding, are these forms all referring to a unique reference of themselves, or is a new one being instantiated every time they're routed to? When a form is created, I want to send its reference to the router and that's how they're stored, I don't want a new one to be created every time the user returns to the menu and clicks on that form again. If you could just clarify that to me. :)

Comment: Then you should design the classes as singletons and simply return this single instance within the factory, I update accordingly.

Comment: @HimBromBeere lol that just makes me want to go study C# from scratch. I was hoping I could toy with Reflection a bit but this was very insightful, thank you for your help. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using reflection, nevertheless i recommend to use a more typesafe approach like the one already posted.

It creates a dictionary with each fieldname and a delegate pointing to its corresponding index method, so you will have the reflection performance hit only once during the cctor run.

```
public static class Router
{
    static frmLogin rLogin = new frmLogin();
    static frmDashboard rDashboard = new frmDashboard();
    static frmReport rReport = new frmReport();

    static readonly Dictionary<string, Action> RoutingDictionary;

    static Router()
    {
        RoutingDictionary = typeof (Router).GetFields(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
            .Where(x => typeof (Form).IsAssignableFrom(x.FieldType))
            .ToDictionary(k => k.Name, v =>
            {
                var form = v.GetValue(null);
                return (Action) form.GetType().GetMethod("Index").CreateDelegate(typeof (Action), form);
            });
    }

    public static void Route(string form)
    {
        RoutingDictionary[form]();
    }
}
```

Comment: This would call the `Index`-method on every call to `Route`, which as far as I understood the OP wants to avoid (see the comments within my answer). However cool solution.+1

Comment: Yeah i see, maybe the OP can clarify his needs by providing the whole scenario in his question.

Comment: @thehennyy No, this works. What I am avoiding is a new object being created for every routing. Of course the index needs to be called on every routing, otherwise what functionality does routing have? Thanks for this post. :)